# Why child class doesnt refresh value of another child class Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've encountered a problem with typescript.
schematically, I have :

- parent abstract class A.
- child class B.
- child class C.

  ```
    export abstract class BasePage {

        public value = 1;

    }

    @Component({...}) // selector, template ...
    export class A extends BasePage{
        constructor(){}

        editValue(){
          this.value = 3;
        }
    }

    @Component({...}) // selector, template ...
    export class B extends BasePage{
        constructor(){}
    }
  ```

  ```html
    <!-- B template -->
    <p> Parent abstract value : {{ value }}<!-- still remain 1 --> </p>
  ```

In parent class A, I have the property "value" which is used in both child classes. But it doesn't refresh in the B class when I launch editValue() in A class simultaneously.

Comment: Because they aren't the same instance

Comment: You would need to have an Observable in the parent class that the child classes could subscribe to

Comment: May be the answer of your question lies in the explanation how javascript understands subclass and parent class, when you call editValue(){
        this.value = 3;
      } this function the "this" belongs to the class A not to the BaseClass

Answer (score 1):

May be the answer of your question lies in the explanation how javascript understands subclass and parent class, when you call

```
editValue(){
        this.value = 3;
      }
```

this function the "this" belongs to the class A not to the BaseClass,

Also in TS when you extend a class you need to call `super()` in the constructor which will initialise `value` as 1, next time when you call the `editValue` you are essentially changing the class property not the parent class property

look how TS is converted in JS from this example from TS playground,

[image]

here you are dealing with different objects